What kind of plug has a round prong and a flat prong?
I’m trying to find out which adapter I can get for this plug. It is for a small Christmas Angel.


The key point to take from the answers below is that you should not be "adapting" this to fit a wall outlet. That's a recipe for a spark show. There was presumably another component providing low-voltage power that you'll need (or a compatible replacement).

@isherwood I think you are misunderstanding OP's use of the word adapter. I think they're asking something like "where can I find a wall wart (adapter) that works with this"

Unfortunately, we can't tell you much with the info provided. Others have identified the type as speaker plug, but that doesn't tell you what voltage/current/polarity. There may be writing on the angel giving more info; with that we may be able to help more.

It's commonly called a "loudspeaker plug" (or "speaker plug").  As there are other types of speaker plug, "speaker plug 2 pin" will get you plenty of results.
The one in your hand is male, the mating part might be called a female plug, or a socket.
They're fairly common for low voltage Christmas lights, but the actual voltage and whether AC or DC depends on the lights.  I have successfully swapped power supplies between lights, but they were labelled

Believe it or not, it's one of those old DIN connectors that used to be common for low voltage devices like computer keyboards in the 1980s.
This one is not exactly what I'm used to because it's only a 2-pin style.
Check out DIN Connectors at Wikipedia and scroll all the way down to the "Other Designs" heading.

Nothing to do with keyboards. It's a speaker plug, as the other answer correctly stated. The fact that there were DIN connectors used for keyboards as well doesn't make it any more related. DIN is nothing else than the name of all German standards from back then, just like ISO nowadays.

While yes DIN connectors were used for keyboards, it might be more relevant to mention that DIN connectors were widely used for audio -- in that light it makes even more sense that the pictured connector was used for loudspeakers, another audio application.
